# Modify appearance of System Calender

Tags: windows

Is there any way of modifying appearance of Windows XP Calender, like highlighting weekends and holidays?

Comment: XP has a calendar? o.O

Comment: I mean DateTime properties windows..

Comment: Any one who can help me here?

Answer (score 2):

The `Date and Time Properties` is intended to set the system time (an unintended secondary use  has become to find out today's date).

That being said, you probably need a real taskbar calendar-- something [Desktop iCalendar Lite](http://download.cnet.com/Desktop-iCalendar-Lite/3000-2124_4-10802583.html?tag=mncol;pop).

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do what you want with the basic calendar of Windows.